# How to prove that a collection of epsilon balls generates a basis for topology?

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry

Specific question:

"Suppose $X$ is a three dimensional Euclidean space with the standard Euclidean metric. Let $Y$ be the subset defined by $Y=\{P_1$ s.t. $P_1=(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $c_1=0\}$ and use the subspace topology for Y. Define a mapping $S:Y\to X$ as $S(a,b,0)=(a,b,+\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$ and define the subset of X by $Z=S(Y)$.

Prove that for every $(a,b)$ in $R^3$, the intersection Z with open balls at center $(a,b,+\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$ and of arbitrary dimension $r$ generates a basis for topology of Z."

My question doesn't specifically want an answer to the above question. rather, I ask for an explanation of the general concepts at play here. How can I go about solving these types of problems, other than saying that it is true by definition (which I think is incorrect). My misunderstanding is more fundamental than situational, so really any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does "… open balls … of arbitrary dimension" mean here? Perhaps "arbitrary radius"?

Comment: open balls I believe refers to an open neighborhood around a point with radius $\epsilon$, in which $\epsilon \gt 0$

Comment: Yes, the question is what "arbitrary dimension" means here.

Comment: I'm not really sure. . .I've copied the question directly from the notes. . .It probably refers to an arbitrary radius

Comment: Okay, let's assume it means "arbitrary radius", since that makes sense. Are you familiar with how a metric induces a topology?

Comment: I know a metric is defined as a distance with a magnitude if the two points are unit and is zero if the points are the same. Additionally the metric follows triangle's inequality. These distances can make up a collection of $\epsilon$ balls that can induce a metric topology. . .Am I getting anywhere?

Comment: Yes, you're getting somewhere. You need to know _how_ the balls induce the topology, and then you look at the restriction $d_Z = d\lvert_{Z\times Z}$, and ponder the relation between the $d_Z$-balls and the intersection of $d$-balls whose centre is in $Z$ with $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept is that you want to show two things namely;
1) Given some arbitrary open set, you can express that open set as a union of basis elements. 
2) Show that if an open set is contained in two basis elements, say B1 and B2, then there is a basis element B3 contained in the intersection of B1 and B2 which also contains that open set.

Showing that (1) and (2) are satisfied by a collection of open sets is sufficient for proving that collection is a basis that generates the topology in question.